# Applet Background image when the image is in another folder

Tags: java, image, background, applet

How can i set a background image for an applet when the image is in another location

background = getImage(getCodeBase(),"image.jpg"); this code works fine and set the background

but i want to set an image as background that is not in the folder that contains the applet class

background = getImage(getCodeBase(),"E://image.jpg"); not works

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please consider modifying your question to include additional information that will help viewers answer it quickly, such as the language you are using.  This is typically reflected in the post's tags.

Comment: It works when using getImage(URL) method instead of getImage(URL,String) and there we can give the absolute path of the image
 background = getImage(new URL("file:\\E:\\download.jpg"));